# Storing send message history on parse.com for a messaging app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using parse.com for my backend for a messaging sort of app. I am at a part now where I want to show a 'chat log' or message history. What is the best way to store a message history on parse?
A new class to store sent messages, or a PFRelation to a message that has been send?

If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: If you're sending messages from Person A to Person B then at some point they have to be on Parse's servers.  Are you deleting them?  You should just be able to query your message class to get a complete chat log.  Can you show the code how you send a message and maybe outline the fields of your message class?

Comment: Well I have it so I create a message, upload it to parse and it sits there idle until I want to send it (its hard to explain without explaining the whole app idea). So because of this I am confused about how to create a chat log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Chat object for each conversation, and store every message in an array of pointers. So when your message is sent, you add it to the chat array.

Showing a chat log will then be as easy as querying for the correct Chat object (using includeKey for the pointer array key, which will fetch all the messages together with the Chat object) and then showing the messages directly.