# Chat application: Get messages between 2 users in Parse query

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am building a chat app using Parse. I want to retrieve chat history between 2 users. In SQL, it could be represented like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE (sender = user1 AND receiver = user2) OR (sender = user2 AND receiver = user1)
```

But I don't know how to convert into a Parse query.

Here my Message model:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

@ParseClassName("Message")
public class Message extends ParseObject {

    public Message() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return getObjectId();
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return getCreatedAt();
    }

    public ParseUser getSender() {
        return getParseUser("sender");
    }

    public void setSender(ParseUser user) {
        put("sender", user);
    }

    public ParseUser getReceiver() {
        return getParseUser("receiver");
    }

    public void setReceiver(ParseUser user) {
        put("receiver", user);
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return getString("content");
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        put("content", content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
String user1;
String user2;

// build first AND condition
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryPart1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
queryPart1.whereEqualTo("sender", user1);
queryPart1.whereEqualTo("receiver", user2);

// build second AND condition
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryPart2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
queryPart2.whereEqualTo("sender", user2);
queryPart2.whereEqualTo("receiver", user1); 

// list all queries condition for next step
List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(queryPart1);
queries.add(queryPart2);

// Compose the OR clause 
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
innerQuery.addAscendingOrder("createdAt"); // apply sorting for creation date ascending (use addDescendingOrder for Desc sorting)

// *** Parse does not allow selection result greater than 1000 elements for query, so you may need to paging your system
//innerQuery.setSkip(10); // skip the first 10 results
//innerQuery.setLimit(200); // limit selection to first 200 elements ( from your skip offset if set, from the first otherwise )

// Run selection asynchronously 
innerQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

  public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    // Do your stuff with 'results' list, if no error has been occurred
    // ...
    // ..
    // .
  }

});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You really should focus on how chat messages are stored rather than how to query them. It seems to me that your model is quite SQL-ish, and this results in rather complex and slow queries and calculations when you later want to show a history.

You should design your model in a more NoSQL way to get the benefits from Parse's NoSQL backend (MongoDB).

When you design your model, start with defining what QUERIES you will perform against it. You could solve your chat history by querying and sorting, but a much better approach performancewise is to make sure your chat history is already there on the server. This will make the query for the history superfast, and the load on your user's device minimal.

One solution suggested here: [Storing send message history on parse.com for a messaging app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330652/storing-send-message-history-on-parse-com-for-a-messaging-app/23334661#23334661)